# How to get content of different url on my other url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

When i enter the url https://www.example.com/ on my browser than it display the data of https://www.example.com/index.php?page=location/state/MX without changing url on browser ie it should remain example.com
How can i do this by htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache, mod_rewrite is your solution. You most likely want to start here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/. If you run into specific issues, I suggest asking more specific questions.

Comment: Yes i am using apache php.Our landing page is http://abc dot com/index.php?page=location/state/MX it would be possible to be just www dot abc dot com ?if yes, how?

Comment: Yes, its possible. With `mod_rewrite` is I wrote in my answer. Start by reading the documentation in the link I posted (or just Google for "mod_rewrite tutorial"). If you have specific issues ask for help.

Comment: can you please provide me exact code.I need it. Its urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue..

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?page=location/state/MX [L]

www dot abc dot com display result of  www dot abc dot com/index.php?page=location/state/MX without changing url ie url still display www dot abc dot com.